# How to understand "if ( obj.length === +obj.length )" Javascript condition statement?

Tags: javascript, syntax, underscore.js, conditional-statements

I have run across a condition statement which I have some difficulties to understand. It looks like (*please note the `+`-sign on the right-hand-side*) this:

`obj.length === +obj.length`.

Can this condition and its purpose/syntax be explained?
Looking at the statement (without knowing it) provokes the impression that it is a dirty  hack of some sort, but I am almost certain that *underscore.js* is rather a well designed library, so there must be a better explanation.

#### Background

- I found this statement used in some functions of the *underscore.js* library ([underscore.js annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html)).
- My guesswork is that this condition statement is somehow related to testing for a variable `obj` to be of Array type? (but I am totally unsure). I have tried to test this using this code.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
testResult1 = myArray.length === +myArray.length;
console.log( testResult1 ); //prints true

var myObject = { foo : "somestring", bar : 123 };
testResult2 = myObject.length === +myObject.length;
console.log( testResult2 ); //prints false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does two tests at once:

- Makes sure that obj.length is a number
- Makes sure that obj.length is not NaN (not a number)

Can also be written as:

```
(typeof obj.length === 'number') && !isNaN(obj.length)
```

*Updated answer: I first said it was equivalent to `typeof obj.length === 'number') && isFinite(obj.length)` but it isn't since it returns true for `+Infinity` and `-Infinity`. Thanks to RobG for pointing that out*

Comment: thanks @some. I like your answer too. in Combination with Quentins answer it completes the picture. I think the syntactic sugar being so lengthy and the pitfall with the needed `&& isFinite(ob.length)` part makes it clear why the **underscore.js** magicians opted for the unary plus operator (besides it is much confusing).

Comment: The second test could also be `!isNaN(obj.length)`. Note that in the original, `Infinity == +Infinity` is true but `isFinite(Infinity)` returns false so the above is perhaps a better test (depending on what the original intent really was).

Comment: @finishingmove It can be anything.... a string, object, boolean, null, undefined... or a number. Just because it is called `length` doesn't mean that it is a number.

Comment: `a = NaN` then `+a` returns `NaN` but `a===+a` returns false (NaN not equals NaN). And `typeof a` also returns `'number'`. That line could be : Make sure that obj.lenght is not NaN

Answer (score 5):

The [unary plus operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) (`+`) converts the RHS into a Number.

This is a test to see if the value is a Number in the first place.

Comment: Yes, though it seems to me that `typeof obj.length == 'number'` would be clearer. :-/

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. So basically it seems it tests the length property to be a `Number`. Is there are more [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) way to achieve the same test result? I looked into `isNumeric(obj.length)` and `obj.length istanceof Number` and those seemingly better options are *false friends*. Any idea for test of a Number?

Comment: Good point (which I thought of after commenting), but without context the reason for wanting to do that is not clear.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace—what is your definition of "a Number"? Is that where `-Infinity < x < +Infinity && x != NaN` ?

Comment: @RobG Good question! I have to say that in between the Javascript's notion of a numeric variable primitive and that what is reflected by the `Number` Javascript object I have to admit that I am at a loss to see exactly what I should answer here. After all intuition is not helping and NaN is somehow a `typeof NaN === "number" // true` strange thing. Can you help?

Comment: I can only say that you should design tests that suit the context in which they will be used. So the test in the OP can only evaluated in the context that it was used, e.g. it will allow `obj.length = Infinity` but not `obj.length = '1'`. I can't guess why anyone would do that.

Comment: @RobG right, `obj.length === +obj.length` returns true for `Infinity`.

Comment: It makes sure that it is a number (not a string), and not NaN.